# "Mutating method sent to immutable object" despite object being NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm using `NSMutableDictionary` and hit this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Here's the code:

```
    // Turn the JSON strings/data into objects
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *invoiceDictFromReq = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//    invoiceDictFromReq = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    invoiceDictFromReq = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:kNilOptions error:&error]];

NSLog(@"invoiceDictFromReq count: %i, key: %@, value: %@", [invoiceDictFromReq count], [invoiceDictFromReq allKeys], [invoiceDictFromReq allValues]);

// Get values and keys from JSON response
self.invoiceDict = [invoiceDictFromReq objectForKey:@"invoice"];
NSNumber *invoiceAmount = [self.invoiceDict objectForKey:@"amount"];
NSNumber *invoiceId = [self.invoiceDict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSNumber *invoiceNumber = [self.invoiceDict objectForKey:@"number"];
NSNumber *checkoutStarted = [self.invoiceDict objectForKey:@"checkoutStarted"];
NSNumber *checkoutCompleted = [self.invoiceDict objectForKey:@"checkoutCompleted"];
NSLog(@"amount: %@, id: %@, number: %@, started: %@, completed: %@", invoiceAmount, invoiceId, invoiceNumber, checkoutStarted, checkoutCompleted);
```

All the console logs indicate that the data is fine. This is where things start to break down.
I pass the `invoiceDict` property to the next view controller:

```
// Pass the invoice to checkoutViewController
[checkoutViewController setInvoiceDict:self.invoiceDict];
```

In CheckoutViewController.m:

```
    // Change invoice checkoutCompleted to true
//    [self.invoiceDict removeObjectForKey:@"checkoutCompleted"];
    [self.invoiceDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"checkoutCompleted"];
```

The error is at `[self.invoiceDict setObject...]`. I made sure that all the dictionaries I use are `NSMutableDictionary`. I left some of the commented-out lines in the code to show the things I've tried and I hit a brick wall. I suppose I can always create a new dictionary. Is that the preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are allocing a dictionary in invoiceDictFromReq and next you are creating another dictionary, you are creating a leak of memory there.
Delete the line

```
NSMutableDictionary *invoiceDictFromReq = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

But your problem is that you are creating a NSMutableDictionary but you are setting to self.invoiceDict a dictionary inside your mutableDictionary, that is not necessarily a mutableDictionary too.
Change the line

```
self.invoiceDict = [invoiceDictFromReq objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```

for

```
self.invoiceDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[invoiceDictFromReq objectForKey:@"invoice"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still gives me the same error. Now, I have invoiceDictFromReq as a property in .h and syntehsized in .m and set it to the data from the json request as self.invoiceDictFromReq = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary...]

Comment: Sorry I changed my answer, it was not that. See if you still have the problem. You don't have to retain invoiceDictFromReq because it's a local variable, but delete the line that you create invoiceDictFromReq for the first time because you have a leak there

Comment: :-). When I saw, "But your problem is that you are creating a NSMutableDictionary but you are setting to self.invoiceDict a dictionary inside your mutableDictionary, that is not necessarily a mutableDictionary too" I knew you hit it on the spot. So foolish of me. Thanks for pointing it out. I shouldn't have assumed that the native json parser returns NSMutableDictionary. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 15):

`NSJSONSerialization` returns immutable objects by default. Here is how to get mutable dictionary from the parser:

- use option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`

or

- use `mutableCopy` on the result

Comment: You don't need to use mutableCopy, just use the result. NSJSONReadingMutableContainers makes not only arrays and dictionaries within the result mutable, but also the result itself.